# Localhost Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: node.js, heroku, localhost

Tenho uma aplicação que roda perfeitamente no herokuApp. Mas quando esta em aplicacao local o build funciona mas a pasta dist apresenta erros. O console.log apresenta os 3 seguintes erros abaixo. Se alguem tiver passado por isso e tiver uma resposta, pois estou sem alternativas.

```
client-vendor-bundle.js:27 TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
at e.watch.sync (client-bundle1.js:10)
at Ht.<anonymous> (client-vendor-bundle.js:48)
at ji.get (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at ji.run (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at ji.update (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at Zr.notify (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at Object.set [as $$state] (client-vendor-bundle.js:27)
at client-vendor-bundle.js:48
at j._withCommit (client-vendor-bundle.js:48)
at j.replaceState (client-vendor-bundle.js:48)ae @ client-vendor-bundle.js:27

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullPath' of undefined
at Ht.e.watch.sync (client-bundle1.js:10)
at ji.run (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at ji.update (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at Zr.notify (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at Object.set [as $$state] (client-vendor-bundle.js:27)
at client-vendor-bundle.js:48
at j._withCommit (client-vendor-bundle.js:48)
at j.replaceState (client-vendor-bundle.js:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (client-bundle1.js:2)
at t (client-vendor-bundle.js:1)ae @ client-vendor-bundle.js:27

client-vendor-bundle.js:27 TypeError: Cannot read property 'i18n' of undefined
at o.t [as $t] (client-bundle1.js:10)
at o.fullText (client-bundle1.js:2)
at ji.get (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at ji.evaluate (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at o.fullText (client-vendor-bundle.js:27)
at o.render (client-bundle1.js:10)
at o.e._render (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at o.r (client-vendor-bundle.js:27)
at ji.get (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
at new ji (client-vendor-bundle.js:32)
```